# how find out a user is logged in already to prevent him log into my site in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net

I have a site , and I want to prevent my users to log in to site for more that one sessions.For example , if a user logged into my site in computer A , I prevent to try to log in to site in computer B (since it is logged in to site in a computer and did not log out)
Is there any solution ?
I have 3 ideas(actually they are bad idea and i am looking for better idea)

1 - use `Session` State

2 - use `Application` State

3 - use `who2` table in sql server

**UPDATE** : I have my user management approach , and i did not use ASP Membership

Comment: What if the user closes his browser? How do you think your application be notified of this event?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov :  exactly . i am looking for such these event

Comment: look no more as such thing doesn't exist. You will only waste your time. The closest you could get is to define some period of inactivity after which you would consider the user logged out by flagging the database field where you would store this information.

Comment: i can not understand you , I am looking for an idea because my ideas are bad exactly for those events you named , so do you have any idea?

Comment: since you cannot be notified that a user has closed his browser the best you could do is to define a period of inactivity after which you would consider the user logged off and update the database where you would keep track of logged in users.

Comment: look , if user close its browser , so its sessions will be expired on server ,is it right ? can i use this idea?

Comment: This won't work. Consider the following scenario. An anonymous user visits your site and logs in. You update a field in the database saying that this user is logged in. The user closes his browser. The same user opens a new browser and a new session and attempts to login again but in your database he is still logged in so you don't allow him to do so.

Comment: ok , any other ideas exist? i am looking for optimum solution

Comment: @DarinDimitrov , OK thanks , send your last comment as an answer to accept it to close this question , thanks again

Comment: why not use a database to store the username's of the users who signout. and then when they are signing in if they are on that list allow them else don't.

Comment: @AliForoughi, posted my comment as answer.

Comment: @Wahtever , what about if user close its browser ?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov , thanks , i am waiting for others, if i dont get any better answer i will accept is as soon as possible,thanks again dude

Comment: @AliForoughi - if the user closes the browser then the user wont signout and then he wont be inserted in the database and wont be allowed to signin on the other Computer.

Comment: @Wahtever , so it is bad dude , yes? try to think more dude hahaha

Comment: @AliForoughi - look dude, if you look at your question you will find that you wrote this _I prevent to try to log in to site in computer B (since it is logged in to site in a computer and did not log out)_. so try to read more dude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is that you have to keep track somewhere on your server (application state, database, ...) a list of authenticated users. When a user signs-in you will first look if he is present in this list. If he is refuse the sign in. If he is not add him to this list and allow him to login. Everytime the user performs some action on your site update the this list with the date when he performed this action. When signing in if the user is present in the list and the date when he lastly performed an action on your site is older than a treshold date you have defined you could allow sign in.